# Can someone explain me this behaviour?

Tags: javascript

Why in the first case there're backslashes while in the second one there is? The escape function shouldn't change anything right? And even if it was the most logic would be `str.replace('\'', '\\\'')` , so... Thanks in advance.

```js
escape = function(str) {
    str = str.replace('\\', '\\\\')
    str = str.replace('\'', '\\\'')
    str = str.replace('\"', '\\\"')
    str = str.replace('\0', '')
    str = str.replace('\r', '\\r')
    str = str.replace('\n', '\\n')
    return str;
}

var original = ("Maura';--");
var escaped = escape("Maura';--");
//var encoded = btoa(escaped);

console.log(original);
console.log(escaped);
//console.log(encoded);
```

**Output:**

*'Maura';--'*

*'Maura\';--'*

Comment: `str = str.replace('\'', '\\\'')` <- you replace a quote character with a slashed quote.

Comment: "shouldn't change anything right" --- if it does not change anything, what's its purpose? PS: if this function has something to do with preventing some sort of injection, you better not use it.

Comment: Yea it's his purpose. Why then?

Comment: Why _what_? ...

Comment: Why should I not use it.

Comment: Because there is a chance there is a _proper_ way to encode data.

Comment: and also because it only replaces the first instance and not anything after that

Comment: You mean there could be a way to inject "Maura';-- bypassing that escape function?

Comment: I mean that writing secure code is hard, you should use whatever the technology provides you to encode data, not to try reimplement it from scratch.

Comment: I see. I'm actually doing this as computery security excercise, so I'm trying to find a why to bypass that basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case you are not apply the `escape` function on the string `original`. In the second case its changed due to second line of the `escape` function

```
str = str.replace('\'', '\\\'')
```

The above line is same as

```
str = str.replace("'", '\\\'').
```

And the second part `\\\'` will become `\'`.